# ¿Cómo enviar correo desde Xamarin Android?

Tags: email, xamarin.android

Estoy intentando enviar un correo desde Xamarin Android pero me marca el siguiente error

"454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later. t16sm738147ott.79 - gsmtp\r"

Ésto es lo que tengo

```
 private void BtnSendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress("********@gmail.com","*******");
            message.To.Add("**********@gmail.com"); 
            message.Subject = "Test Correo";
            message.Body = "Prueba 1";
            //client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer Gmail se esta quejando de muchos intentos fallidos, tienes estas opciones:

- Verifica que el usuario y contraseña sean correctos
- Habilita en Gmail el logeo desde aplicaciones de terceros; esto permite que puedas usar tu cuenta de Gmail en aplicaciones No oficiales de Google, entra a  esta [liga](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)(debes estar logeado con tu cuenta de Gmail) y habilita la casilla

Comment: Cierto, faltaba el permiso a terceros como lo mencionaste, la casilla aún estaba desmarcada, gracias por la ayuda :)